# Datepicker not appearing for multiple time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, datepicker

It is the question related to: [Nested Model Form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1). 
I want to add new `text` field with `date-picker` on click button with class `.add_fields`. The new generated field are of same class name and different id.
My problem is: The date picker is not appearing while click the button with class '.add_fields' for new field. 
My coffeescript code is:

```
$('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
    time = new Date().getTime()
    regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
    $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
    event.preventDefault()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding new fields to DOM on click of the button, though the newly added fields have the same class but they won't have the datepicker attached with them as datepicker was attached to that class elements before they were added to the DOM.

To attach the datepicker to dynamically added fields, you need to remove it first then re-attach. e.g. If you have field with class `datepicker` and you would need to change your javascript code to:

```
$('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
  time = new Date().getTime()
  regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
  $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))

  //remove the hasDatepicker class from the fields and re-intialise datepicker.
  $('.datepicker').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'})
  event.preventDefault()
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the content of your `data('fields')`. but there must be the text field in there, right?

After inserting the new DOM elements from `data('fields')` you have to initialize the datepicker:

```
$(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time)).find('.date-picker').datepicker()
```

P.S.: I'm not sure whether `$(this).before(content)` returns `$(this)` or `$(content)` (jQuery docu doesn't explain). Maybe you have to adjust the `find`.

Comment: BTW: Manjo's answer reinitializes **all** datepickers on the page, this code initializes only the new inserted one.